# quick question on naming things related to metrics and topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

sorry if this has been asked, but I am confused about how to name things related to topologies and metrics.

In topology, A topology on $X$ will be $\mathcal{O} \subset P(X)$ where it satisfies the three conditions. Where $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is named a topological space. But, I am confused about why we call $(X,d)$ a metric space. Would a better way to define this is the metric on $X$, which is the distance function $d$ that induces a topology on $X$(through the basis of balls) denoted as $\mathcal{O}$ where $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is called the metric space.

Comment: We call $(X,d)$ a metric space because it has a defined metric function on it, and we're considering them as a pair together for a relevant purpose; $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is the same, in that we look at it in a topological context and have defined a topology $\mathcal{O}$ on it. A metric will necessarily have an induced topology, generated by open balls, but the reverse need not be true, so they're distinct notions. You might call $(X,\mathcal{O}_d)$ that induced space. I'm not sure if that answers your question, but it's hard to ascertain what kind of answer you'd like in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

We call $(X,d)$ a metric space, because $X$ is a set and $d$ is a metric. There's nothing more to that. Just like we call $(X,\mathcal{O})$ a topological space, because $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{O}$ a topology. We cannot call $(X,\mathcal{O})$ a metric space when $\mathcal{O}$ is not a metric. That would be very confusing.

You are right, that every metric induces a topology. But that doesn't mean that metric spaces are topological spaces. Besides formality, there isn't even a one-to-one correspondance between them: mutliple different metrics may induce the same topology (a.k.a. [topologically equivalent metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics)). We can call $(X,\mathcal{O})$ a [metrizable topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space), meaning that $\mathcal{O}$ arises from some metric. But **it is not** a metric space.

And sometimes we are interested in metric properties instead of topological properties. For example in data analysis. Two different data sets may be topologically equivalent, but metrically very different. Another example is almost entire analysis, where completeness of [the Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) plays crucial role, even though there are non-complete metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ that induce the same topology.

Given two metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X',d')$ we often consider the concept of a continuous function $X\to X'$ between them. As it turns out, continuity depends on the underlying topologies only, not on concrete metric. But as I said earlier, maybe we are interested in a stronger notion of distance-preserving functions, a.k.a. [isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry). These require concrete metrics. For example $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ but not isometric (at least under the standard metric on both sides). So is $\mathbb{R}$ different from $(0,1)$? Depends on what properties we are looking at.

So all depends on what we are trying to achieve. Sometimes authors simply treat metric spaces as topological spaces. Meaning they only look at the induced topology. But you should always remember that these ideas are different.

Metric is not a topology. From a topological point of view it doesn't matter how far is Paris from Rome. But clearly it matters to you when you want to travel that distance, no?